# Streaming Audio from PC to Mac via Bluetooth?

Tags: windows, macos, audio, bluetooth, playback

Heyo community! Long time viewer, first time poster here <3

Q: I have a PC laptop (acer Aspire, windows 8) and I would like to stream audio to my Macbook Pro via bluetooth to the PC. Is this possible?

Background: I've gotten the mac to stream audio to the PC. But not the other way around. My current issue is that I can't add the Mac as a playback device in the "Sound" window on my PC. Even though it is listed as a device in the "Devices and Printers" section of control panel.

Reason: On the Macbook I have an Apogee duet and reference monitors. I want to play audio from the PC through the speakers. I work in Ableton live on both computers but it's a hassle to send files to the mac to have them played on nice speakers. I've tried using the audio jack and sending the audio to the Duet device but due to (man I can't remember the exact reason) something about the audio card setup or grounding, there is this really bad sound that results.

Much love.
And Cats. =^.^=

Comment: What exactly would be the use of this?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. This question is very broad, and if you can do further research and find a more specific question to ask, we can be more helpful.